# Cant access my "Category" model in html file

Tags: django

I cant access my Category model in html.

I access from shell by tapping " Category.objects.all()". I access my Item model but not Category model. It's about Category model's structure i guess. But i cannot figure out how to fix this. I cant reach even while i use "{{categories}}"

Here's my models.py:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name="Title")

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Category"
        verbose_name_plural = "Categories"
        ordering = ['title']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Item(models.Model):
    seller = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, verbose_name="Category", on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    title_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/img', default='None')
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    updated_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name="Updated at")
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    is_published = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name="Is published?")
    end_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=False, default=seven_days_hence)

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

views.py :

```
def category_list(request):
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'blog/item_list.html', {'categories': categories})


def item_list(request):
    items = Item.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('published_date')
    return render(request, 'blog/item_list.html', {'items': items})
```

urls.py :

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.item_list, name='item_list'),
    path('', views.category_list, name='category_list'),
    path('item/<int:pk>/', views.item_detail, name='item_detail'),
    path('item/new/', views.item_new, name='item_new'),
    path('item/<int:pk>/edit/', views.item_edit, name='item_edit'),
]
```

base.html :

```
% load staticfiles %}
<html>
    <head>
        <title>İkinci El Eşya Al Sat</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
        <link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster&subset=latin,latin-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/blog.css' %}">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="page-header">
            <a href="{% url 'item_new' %}" class="top-menu"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a>
            <h1><a href="/">İkinci El Eşya Al Sat</a></h1>
        </div>
        <div class="content container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    {% block content %}
                    {% endblock %}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

item_list.html :

```
{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    {% for category in categories %} {{ category.title }} {% endfor %}
    {% for item in items %}
        <div class="item">
            <div class="date">
                {{ item.published_date }}
            </div>
            <h1><a href="{% url 'item_detail' pk=item.pk %}">{{ item.title }}</a></h1>
            <img src="{{ item.title_image.url }}" alt="img">
            <p>{{ item.text|linebreaksbr }}</p>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: ```{% for category in categories %}
    {{ category.title }}
{% endfor %}```

Comment: you haven't defined `items` in your context so how can you say "I access my Item model". As mentioned by @gachdavit `categories` is a QuerySet, so it will probably print in your template as `<QuerySet>` or something similar (look in your HTML source in your browser). You need to loop through the Queryset to see the items in it.

Comment: I didn't write all parts about "items" to be short. I know hot to make loop but I haven't tried it as a loop without seeing it as queryset.

Comment: Well we can't really help you unless you show what code you actually used and what the problem is.

Comment: Fixed. The problem is i use 2 views and 2 urlpattern path that routes are same. I reedit my views just change item_list function like this and everything work perfect :  `def item_list(request):
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    items = Item.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('published_date')
    return render(request, 'blog/item_list.html', {'categories': categories, 'items': items})`